# Android's Expanded Notifications - Both Standard ContentView and custom BigContentView after expansion

Tags: android, notifications, remoteview, expandable, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I've made a custom RemoteView in JellyBean, as described [here](http://www.feras.us/blog/custom-rich-notification-view-android/), and set it as the bigContentView of a notification.

```
notification.bigContentView = customNotifView;
```

I'm trying to have the custom layout placed **below** the standard contentView after the expansion; something like [this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3470191/richnotif.png).

The problem is that the custom layout **overrides** the standard contentView after the expansion.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much simple solution would look like this

```
        RemoteViews contentView = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.big_notificaiton_layout);
        fillTextViews(profile, contentView);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, NotificationChannelHelper.Channel.Channel.getId())
                .setContentIntent(intent)
                .setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.profile_name_is_active, profile.getTitle()))
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle())
                .setCustomBigContentView(contentView)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
```

You have to set `NotificationCompat.DecoratedCustomViewStyle()`.

Comment: "Added in API 24" and this question is from 2014, that's why nobody mentioned it. Thanks for the follow up!

Answer (score 5):

I solved by creating a custom layout for the contentView called `layout_base_content_notification.xml`, which is exactly the same (handmade) layout Android provides for notifications.

```
RemoteViews collapsedViews = new RemoteViews(c.getPackageName(), R.layout.layout_base_content_notification);
Notification noti = builder.build();
noti.contentView = collapsedViews;
```

Then I've included it in a customLayout, called `layout_big_content_notification.xml`:

```
<include
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
layout="@layout/layout_base_content_notification" />
```

And added it as a bigContentView:

```
RemoteViews expandedViews = new RemoteViews(c.getPackageName(), R.layout.layout_big_content_notification);
noti.bigContentView = expandedViews;
```

Now, after the expansion, the bigContentView replaces the contentView, but their header is the same.

Please let me know if there is a better solution.

Comment: What "c" stands for? From c.getPackageName()

Comment: context: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getPackageName()

Answer (score 0):

You need to create your own `RemoteViews`, then indicate that you want the expanded content to inherit your custom `RemoteViews`.

```
RemoteViews expandedView = new RemoteViews(YOUR CONTEXT.getPackageName(), YOUR CUSTOM LAYOUT);
 Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
 notification.bigContentView = expandedView;
```

or check this [link.](http://www.feras.us/blog/custom-rich-notification-view-android/)

Comment: Thank you @Harshit, but this tutorial doesn't provide any example of custom bigContentView. I really need to do that, because none of the default styles corresponds to my requirements.

Comment: That is exactly what I'm doing (in fact the link you provided is the same I've put in my question). The problem is that the expandedViews **replaces** the default contentView of the notification, while I'd like to **append** it after the expansion... I mean, I need both contentView and bigContentView on screen, at the same time.